# Accidental recursion, blowing up the stack with Seq.append, without using `rec`

Tags: recursion, f#, stack-overflow

I had code that was waiting to blow up something lurking around. Using F# 4.1 `Result` it is similar to this:

```
module Result =
    let unwindSeq (sourceSeq: #seq<Result<_, _>>) =
        sourceSeq
        |> Seq.fold (fun state res -> 
            match state with
            | Error e -> Error e
            | Ok innerResult ->
                match res with
                | Ok suc -> 
                    Seq.singleton suc
                    |> Seq.append innerResult
                    |> Ok
                | Error e -> Error e) (Ok Seq.empty)
```

The obvious bottleneck here is `Seq.singleton` added to `Seq.append`. I understand that this is slow (and badly written), **but why does it have to blow up the stack?** I don't think that `Seq.append` is inherently recursive...

```
// blows up stack, StackOverflowException
Seq.init 1000000 Result.Ok
|> Result.unwindSeq
|> printfn "%A"
```

And as an aside, to unwind a sequence of `Result`, I fixed this function by using a simple `try-catch-reraise`, but that feels sub-par too. Any ideas as to how to do this more idiomatically without force-evaluating the sequence or blowing up the stack?

Not-so-perfect unwinding (it also forces the result-fail type), but at least without pre-evaluation of the sequence:

```
let unwindSeqWith throwArgument (sourceSeq: #seq<Result<_, 'a -> 'b>>) =
    try 
        sourceSeq
        |> Seq.map (throwOrReturnWith throwArgument)
        |> Ok
    with
    | e -> 
        (fun _ -> raise e)
        |> Error
```

Comment: Do you happen to be running this in FSI or in a debug build?  If so, tail-call optimization may be disabled.  Not that it looks like you're doing anything tail-recursive in this code sample, but it might be something to check.

Comment: @Aaron good point. While in the main project it blows up regardless of debug or release, the example above I only tried with debug settings on. Let me check.

Comment: `Seq.append` is not recursive, but `Seq.fold` is.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin I think that depends on the version of F#.  Looking at the source on GitHub, `Seq.fold` currently uses a for-loop and a mutable accumulator, but it used to be tail-recursive:  https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs

Comment: @Aaron, I was away for a moment, but just tested a Release build: the SOE just happens a lot faster, which is expected, other than that it's just the same. And @fyodor I only checked the recent `Seq` library implementation since I used the latest FSharp.Core and indeed, I don't think either `Seq.fold` or `Seq.append` is defined recursively.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the idiomatic way of folding a sequence of `Result`s in the way you suggest would be:

```
let unwindSeq<'a,'b> =
    Seq.fold<Result<'a,'b>, Result<'a seq, 'b>> 
        (fun acc cur -> acc |> Result.bind (fun a -> cur |> Result.bind (Seq.singleton >> Seq.append a >> Ok))) 
        (Ok Seq.empty)
```

Not that this will be any faster than your current implementation, it just leverages `Result.bind` to do most of the work.  I believe the stack is overflowing because a recursive function somewhere in the F# library, likely in the `Seq` module.  My best evidence for this is that materializing the sequence to a `List` first seems to make it work, as in the following example:

```
let results = 
    Seq.init 2000000 (fun i -> if i <= 1000000 then Result.Ok i else Error "too big") 
    |> Seq.toList

results
|> unwindSeq
|> printfn "%A"
```

However, this may not work in your production scenario if the sequence is too big to materialize in memory.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a more idiomatic way of writing it, except that creating a generic value changes the type of `Result.unwindSeq`. Repeating at least one argument allows the generics to be resolved properly (I've often wondered why this type inference limitation exists, but that's another discussion). However, it suffers the same SOE exception, though it appears to come up a little slower (but that's just a feeling, it's not that I can do exact timings since I cannot catch the SOE).

Comment: About `List`, I actually need an implementation that doesn't consume the sequence. It is allowed to access members successfully until a non-successful match is found, which may or may not be reached. As a consequence, my original implementation with `Seq.fold` was the wrong approach already. But the real bummer here is the miraculous slowness of `Seq.singleton >> Seq.append` (or the piped version of the same).

Comment: I've [reported this here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5139) as I think this is a bug. Replacing `Seq.singleton >> Seq.append` with `seq { yield! innerResult, yield suc}` alleviates the problem, no SOE anymore.

Comment: My last comment is wrong, turns out I made a mistake, as the Github discussion shows. As you also found, either solution throws an SOE. As Don Syme mentions, it is not a "hidden" recursive function, it is just the nature of the beast: prepending to a sequence requires nesting since sequences are evaluated lazily. Materializing to a list _first_ requires an extra iteration. The better solution is to change `state` to be a list, to `cons` on that list and to `List.rev` afterwards. `List.toSeq` is O(1), so that's fine. Overall performance is much better, and no SOE anymore.